# Google's Closure compiler, make the output file in one line

Tags: google-closure-compiler

Is there an option for making the output file of the Closure compiler into one single line?

It is wrapping the code at some point, inserting a new line, and I didn't find an option to change this behavior.

Thanks

Comment: This is a feature.  Some older browsers will choke on ultra-long lines in script files.

Comment: Stephen's comment should probably be an Answer so this question can be marked as Answered and Accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be NO, it cannot be disabled. It is a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this using the Java API, 0 is used to indicate no break:

http://www.google.com/codesearch#l5BkQmivP-Y/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions.java&q=lineLengthThreshold%20package:http://closure-compiler%5C.googlecode%5C.com&type=cs&l=1797